# Javascript create new object from class name in string

Tags: javascript, new-operator

I've got this little bit of non working code:

```
PackageLoader.prototype.activate = function(name) {
    this.activePackages.push(new name());
}
```

What I'd like this to do is to push a new instance to the activePackages array, if the name it gets is a string. How to achieve this?

Comment: Where is this function? You have to have a way of finding the thing you want to push first. Would you rather make sure you pass the right function instead of finding the function in this step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bracket notation if it is in global scope

```
this.activePackages.push(new window[name]());
```

Answer (score 2):

If `name` does not refer to a "class" in the global scope, you can safely use `eval`:

```
function toConstructor(className) {
    if (!/^[$_a-z][$_a-z0-9.]*$/i.test(className)) {
        throw new Error("Invalid class name: " + className);
    }

    try {
        return eval(className);
    }
    catch (error) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
var Foo = {
    Bar: {
        Baz: function() {}
    }
};

var Klass1 = toConstructor("XMLHttpRequest");

var xhr = new Klass1();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {};

var Klass2 = toConstructor("Foo.Bar.Baz");
var baz = new Klass2(3);
console.log(baz.x); // logs 3

var Klass3 = toConstructor("I.Do.Not.Exist");

console.log(Klass3); // logs NULL
```